# How to configure a bridge for VMs on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop

Tags: networking

I just got a Dell XPS laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to setup a bridge for my VMs so that they can join the same network that my laptop is on. I want them each to have their own IP on the network.

How can I setup such a bridge? I'm primarily on one of two wireless networks: work and home. I'm never on a wired network.

I've followed a number of different tutorials, but they all end with my wlp interface never coming up.

The easiest way to reproduce the problem is to have a /etc/network/interface file that looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports wlp58s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

The walkthroughs that I took that from had eth0 where I put wlp58s0, because I don't have an eth0 because I guess the naming scheme was changed as part of systemd changes. (Note: I'm using network-manager, not systemd-networkd).

Thanks in avance!

Comment: Might also be helpful to know what hypervisior you are using kvm/qemu?

Comment: KVM, but at the point I'm stuck at, I haven't even touched the hypervisor yet.

Comment: If you want an easy way to set it up you could look into virt-manager package as a gui or other libvirt based stuff to set it up.  Also does it not work at home or just not at work as I have heard workplaces and schools sometimes block bridging somehow.